# Счетчик в getResources Modx

Tags: modx

Когда идет вывод через снипет **getResources**, есть ли возможность задать какой то счетчик?

Например, в обычном php, когда перебираем элементы через **foreach**, пишем так

```
$k=1;
foreach ($rows as $row){
    ...
    $k++;
}
```

и тогда можно создавать условия, например

```
if ($k==1) { ... }
```

Как это сделать в Modx в снипете getResources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Плейсхолдер `[[+idx]]` увеличивается на 1 с каждой итерацией.